# Tensorflow Metrics per class result issue

Tags: tensorflow

To evaluate the ai model performance per class, I would like to calculate the Accuracy per class.
But during training, the metric value is the same for all classes. But this common value is different from each class accuracy value when I run the training with only one output metric. I have tested independently my custom metric function and it provides different values for each class. Consequently, I am guessing there is a memory share. Could you advise how I can modify my code ?
Do you have any advise ?
Thanks

In the File A :

```
class_metrics = MetricsPerClass(classes=self.classes)
metrics_list = list(class_metrics.metrics_dict.values()) 
metrics = self.segmentation_metricloss_prefixe_name: metrics_list}
```

In file B :

```
class MetricsPerClass(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self,
                 name='MetricsPerClass',
                 classes=["Class1", "Class2", "Class3", "Class4", "Class5", "Class6", "Class7"],
                 **kwargs):

        super(MetricsPerClass, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.classes = classes
        
        for i, _ in enumerate(self.classes):
            name = self.classes[i]
            self.metrics_dict[name] = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name=name)
        

    def reset_states(self):
        for metric in self.metrics_dict.values():
            metric.reset_states()

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred):
        lbls = tf.argmax(tf.reshape(y_true, [-1, len(self.classes)]), 1)
        preds = tf.argmax(tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1, len(self.classes)]), 1)
        for i, class_name in enumerate(self.classes):
            in_c = tf.equal(lbls, i)
        
            with tf.name_scope(class_name):
                class_metric_acc = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(lbls, preds, name=class_name, sample_weight=in_c)
                self.metrics_dict[class_name] = class_metric_acc
        
    def result(self):
        results = {}
        for name, metric in self.metrics_dict.items():
             results[name] = metric.result().numpy()
        return results
```

Comment: how did you structure your Class-wise Predictions and Labels? how did you do the Proper Weighting in sample_weight?

Comment: My model perform a picture segmentation analysis. 
My training masks as prepared before training with to_categorical. Is this what you wanted to know ?

Comment: Ensure that the shape of your output masks matches the expected shape. For example, if you have 7 classes, each pixel should be represented by a vector of length 7. Also,your model predictions (y_pred) should have the same shape as your to_categorical processed masks (y_true).Verify that the output layer of your model is correctly configured to match the number of classes and is using an appropriate activation function (like softmax for multi-class segmentation).

Comment: I confirm my model has a last layer taking into account softmax and the number of class. If it was not the case, I think I also should get an error. Isn't it ?